# Reccurence relation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recursive-algorithms

Closed form of $\ nT_n  = 3(n-1)T_{n-1} + 1, n \ge 1$

I've tried calculating some terms, and looking it up on wolframalpha,
it sais the generating function is $\frac{exp(x)}{1-3x}$. Where do i start?

Comment: Do you know what generating function is?

Answer (score 1):

First make a substitution $B_n = nT_n$ so this recursion becomes $B_n = 3B_{n-1} +1$.

Next add $\frac{1}{2}$ to both sides to get $B_n + \frac{1}{2} = 3B_{n-1} +\frac{3}{2}$.

Now let $A_n = B_n + \frac{1}{2}$ this becomes $A_n = 3A_{n-1}$ which you can easily tell has closed form $A_n = \frac{3^n}{2}$.

Translating it all back we get $T_n = \frac{3^n - 1}{2n}$.

Comment: If you replace $nT_n$ on the left side by $B_n$ and $(n-1)T_{n-1}$ on the right side by $B_{n-1}$ you get $B_n = 3B_{n-1} +1$ as I said.  As far as the multiplicative factor you need to use the condition $T_1 =1$.

Comment: OK the first.  I don't see $T_1=1$ as given.  I guess you are assuming $T_0=0$

Comment: It doesn't matter what $T_0$ is, when $n=1$ the recursion becomes $1\cdot T_1 = 3(1-1)T_0 +1$. So $T_1 =1$ always.